# ASPxNewscontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I try to make pop up from `ASPxNewscontrol` and put `javascript:void('0')` in `NavigateUrlField` and then an error raised:

> A field with the name 'javascript:void('0')' was not found on the selected data source.

i'm using `XPODataSource` for the source of data.

Comment: Thanks for edit @J. Steen :D, i'm newbie,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `NavigateUrlFormatString` property

```
       <dxnc:ASPxNewsControl ID="ASPxNewsControl1" runat="server" 
             DataSourceID="..." 
             NavigateUrlFormatString="javascript:void('{0}');" >

             ......

         </dxnc:ASPxNewsControl>
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you Wildan Thank's

Answer (score 0):

From `ASPxNewsControl.NavigateUrlField` doc article: A string value that specifies the name of the data source field which contains item URLs.

Read [ASPxNewsControl.NavigateUrlField](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxNewsControlASPxNewsControl_NavigateUrlFieldtopic) for detailed explanation.